# SQL Help in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql

I am very new to .net and I am having issues with executing an SQL query and then parsing the results.

I want to query my table and then parse the results into a JSON output.

My code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchAdmin(string querystring, int querytype)
{
   SqlDataAdapter dataadapter;
   DataSet ds;

   UserDbContext db = new UserDbContext();

   string query = "select * from users where role='member' and SUBSTRinG(lname, 1, 1) = test string' ORDER BY lname ASC";

   db.Users.SqlQuery(query, null);

   return View();
}
```

I am new to .net and have previously always used PHP as my development language for web. Can someone point me in the right direction of what to do next?

Comment: If you're using a `UserDbContext` (assuming this is from Entity Framework), then you should **not** mix it with `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet`. EF is all about turning SQL output into **proper** .NET objects - and this is fundamentally different than fiddling around with columns/rows in a `DataSet`

Comment: the query string is invalid SQL. What is `test string'`? I would have expected something like `'A'` there, as yuo are comparing _only_ the leftmost character of `lname` to something. Anyway,m in this case you are at _least_ missing a single quote :)

Comment: So how would I turn my query into, for example, a list of User objects?

Comment: The sql statement has been edited from my actual code as it featured a variable from my previous PHP code. My problem is with accessing the results and using them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you know this will work only when you do POST
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult SearchAdmin(string querystring, int querytype)

if you want same code on GET REMOVE 
`[HttpPost]`

1. SELECT * is bad practice  name the columns for fast results
2. very bad choice doing substring... no index help NO NEED FROM SUBSTRING!!!!
   make numeric  'member' ==> role='1' if possible query will run faster
   this will produce FALSE ALLWAYS because you are taking from left 1 letter
   SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

in the where clause  and also missing quote '
and SUBSTRinG(lname, 1, 1) = test string'

here how I return JSON and consume in jQuery client side

```
public class JsonResponse
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string JSONdata{ get; set; }
    public int messageID { get; set; }

   // public string ExtendSomeOtherDataMessageIfNeed { get; set; }
}

public class SearchAdminModel
{
    public string querystring{ get; set; }
    public int querytype{ get; set; }
}

public class myClassModel
{
    public string SQLColumName1{ get; set; }
    public int SQLColumName2{ get; set; }
}



 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SearchAdmin(SearchAdminModel model)
 {
  JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse(); 
  bool hasError=false;

   //MY DAL block access code return out hasError
   // I usually used List<of_myClassModel> and dump to JSON
   // oprion 2 easy Load to DataTable  like you query with * and dump to JSON


   response.JSONdata = "";    // you can use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer, .NET 4.5 serialize or NewtonJson



   response.success =hasError;
        if(!hasError){ 
            response.messageID =messageID ; //if do JavaScript side of messaging skiping serverside message
            response.message = cmpMessages.MessageToString(cmpMessages.Messages.MessagesSuccess);
        }
        else
        {  
            response.messageID =messageID ; //if do JavaScript side of messaging skiping serverside message
         response.message = cmpMessages.MessageToString(cmpMessages.Messages.DBError);
        }


        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet is important in the end to return value

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert DataTable to Json string,

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
}
rows.Add(row);
}
string strJsonOutput=  serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

you can get more details on http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/05/c-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-c.html

let me know for further help.

Comment: How do I get the datatable in the first place. based on my original code?

Comment: yes you can get DataTable after execute your sql query.

Comment: so I use  db.Users.SqlQuery(query, null, User); and then what?

Comment: What db.Users.SqlQuery(query, null, User) returns?